# regex to contain only ascii chars on string on java

Tags: java, regex

im trying to validate string to match all ascii chars on java with regex.
if there is only ascii chars return true, if there is even single char which is not ascii char return false.

i tried the following:

```
Pattern.compile("[^ -~\\r\\n\\t]+").matcher(password).find();
```

and also tried this:

```
Pattern.compile("[^\\Q A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\\E]").matcher(password).find();
```

but it didnt worked.
the string im trying to validate:

```
"abตcdefgh12+"
```

but both codes return to me true, which means its contains only ascii chars which is not... i want that this string will return false.

thanks!

Comment: You'll need anchors, such as `^` and `$`.

Comment: You have to be more specific about what you mean by ASCII chars.  Printable?  Non-printable?  Control characters?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[^ -~\\r\\n\\t]+").matcher(password).find()` matches a char other than ASCII printable char or CR/LF/TAB anywhere in a string. It MUST work.

Comment: "but both codes return to me true, *which means its contains only ascii chars*" isn't right. `find()` checks if specified regex can be found in text, not if *entire* text `matches` the regex as a whole. Lets simplify your example a little. If we have regex like `"[^a]"` and we try to `find()` it in text like `"abc"` result would be `true` because such text contains `b` and `c` which fulfill `[^a]`.

Comment: @Pshemo, you are very sharp. i replaced the find() with matches() and removed the ^ char and is working! many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isPureAscii(String s) {
        return Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(s);
}
```

**Reference:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: thanks! it seems it working also in addtition to the option of regex.